# Error al enviar peticion fetch a fichero local

Tags: json, reactjs, api, fetch, peticion

cree el siguiente json el cual se llama Basedatos.json

luego a traves de una peticion fetch, quiero acceder a los datos:

Sin embargo me aparece el siguiente error: "VM845:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Alguien sabe como solucionar el problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu json está mal-formado. La razon puede ser variada pero lo mas probable:

1. Hay algun error de dedo en tu archivo json.
2. Hay algun símbolo invisible en el archivo (cambias entre windows y mac?)

Puedes usar alguna de las muchas paginas en linea para rapidamente validar que tu archivo json está bien hecho: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=json+validator+online

Consejo extra, no postees un screenshot. Copia y pega tu codigo siempre.